# Eas android build (eas build --platform android) fails. react-native-firebase_messaging:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED

Tags: android, react-native, build.gradle, react-native-firebase, eas

I am trying to build my app and it keeps failing. I am not using bare react native rather expo managed workflow I believe.

Whenever I build for development (`eas build --platform android --profile development`) it builds fine. But when I build for production (`eas build --platform android`) it gives me tons of error.

Error:

```
    Task :react-native-firebase_messaging:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED
    [stderr] An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.8.0_342). Please file a bug against the Java compiler via the Java bug reporting page (http://bugreport.java.com) after checking the Bug Database (http://bugs.java.com) for duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnostic in your report. Thank you.
    [stderr] java.lang.AssertionError: annotationType(): unrecognized Attribute name MODULE (class com.sun.tools.javac.util.UnsharedNameTable$NameImpl)
    [stderr]    at com.sun.tools.javac.util.Assert.error(Assert.java:133)
    [stderr]    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeAnnotations.annotationType(TypeAnnotations.java:231)
    [stderr]    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeAnnotations$TypeAnnotationPositions.separateAnnotationsKinds(TypeAnnotations.java:294)
    [stderr]    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeAnnotations$TypeAnnotationPositions.visitMethodDef(TypeAnnotations.java:1066)
    [stderr]    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodDecl.accept(JCTree.java:778)
    [stderr]    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner.scan(TreeScanner.java:49)
    [stderr]    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeAnnotations$TypeAnnotationPositions.scan(TypeAnnotations.java:275)
    [stderr]    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner.scan(TreeScanner.java:57)
    [stderr]    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeAnnotations$TypeAnnotationPositions.visitClassDef(TypeAnnotations.java:1042)
    [stderr]    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCClassDecl.accept(JCTree.java:693)
    [stderr]    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner.scan(TreeScanner.java:49)
    [stderr]    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeAnnotations$TypeAnnotationPositions.scan(TypeAnnotations.java:275)
    [stderr]    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeAnnotations$1.run(TypeAnnotations.java:127)
    [stderr]    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Annotate.flush(Annotate.java:152)
    [stderr]    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Annotate.enterDone(Annotate.java:129)
    [stderr]    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.complete(Enter.java:512)
    [stderr]    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.main(Enter.java:471)
    [stderr]    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.enterTrees(JavaCompiler.java:982)
    [stderr]    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:857)
    [stderr]    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:523)
    [stderr]    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall(JavacTaskImpl.java:129)
    [stderr]    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:138)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.internal.compiler.java.IncrementalCompileTask.call(IncrementalCompileTask.java:77)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.AnnotationProcessingCompileTask.call(AnnotationProcessingCompileTask.java:94)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.ResourceCleaningCompilationTask.call(ResourceCleaningCompilationTask.java:57)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:55)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:40)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.delegateAndHandleErrors(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:97)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:51)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:37)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.AnnotationProcessorDiscoveringCompiler.execute(AnnotationProcessorDiscoveringCompiler.java:51)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.AnnotationProcessorDiscoveringCompiler.execute(AnnotationProcessorDiscoveringCompiler.java:37)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.ModuleApplicationNameWritingCompiler.execute(ModuleApplicationNameWritingCompiler.java:46)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.ModuleApplicationNameWritingCompiler.execute(ModuleApplicationNameWritingCompiler.java:36)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompiler.execute(CleaningJavaCompiler.java:53)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.IncrementalCompilerFactory.lambda$createRebuildAllCompiler$0(IncrementalCompilerFactory.java:98)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.IncrementalResultStoringCompiler.execute(IncrementalResultStoringCompiler.java:61)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.IncrementalResultStoringCompiler.execute(IncrementalResultStoringCompiler.java:45)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompileJavaBuildOperationReportingCompiler$2.call(CompileJavaBuildOperationReportingCompiler.java:59)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompileJavaBuildOperationReportingCompiler$2.call(CompileJavaBuildOperationReportingCompiler.java:51)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:62)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$call$2(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.callWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:54)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompileJavaBuildOperationReportingCompiler.execute(CompileJavaBuildOperationReportingCompiler.java:51)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.performCompilation(JavaCompile.java:345)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.performIncrementalCompilation(JavaCompile.java:239)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.compile(JavaCompile.java:211)
    [stderr]    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    [stderr]    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    [stderr]    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    [stderr]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:104)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalInputsTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalInputsTaskAction.java:32)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:51)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AbstractIncrementalTaskAction.execute(AbstractIncrementalTaskAction.java:25)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:29)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$2.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:494)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:479)
org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:83)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:44)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:189)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:39)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildWorkExecutor.java:40)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildWorkExecutor.access$000(DefaultBuildWorkExecutor.java:24)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildWorkExecutor$1.proceed(DefaultBuildWorkExecutor.java:48)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:49)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildWorkExecutor.java:40)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildWorkExecutor.java:33)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.execution.IncludedBuildLifecycleBuildWorkExecutor.execute(IncludedBuildLifecycleBuildWorkExecutor.java:36)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.execution.DeprecateUndefinedBuildWorkExecutor.execute(DeprecateUndefinedBuildWorkExecutor.java:44)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.execution.BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkerExecutor$ExecuteTasks.run(BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkerExecutor.java:57)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.execution.BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkerExecutor.execute(BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkerExecutor.java:42)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.runWork(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:260)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doClassicBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:172)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:148)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:124)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.create(GradleBuildController.java:72)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.create(GradleBuildController.java:67)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:213)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:67)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:56)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:31)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:63)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.run(FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.java:77)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:41)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:49)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:44)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:62)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$call$2(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.callWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:54)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:44)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.lambda$execute$0(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:59)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:86)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:58)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.lambda$execute$0(BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:33)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.BuildTreeState.run(BuildTreeState.java:53)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:27)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:104)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:55)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:64)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:37)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.lambda$execute$0(SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:54)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.internal.session.BuildSessionState.run(BuildSessionState.java:67)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:50)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:59)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:31)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:55)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:41)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:47)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:31)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:65)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:39)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:29)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:35)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:78)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:50)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:63)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:84)
    [stderr] at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:52)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    [stderr]    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    [stderr]    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    [stderr]    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    [stderr]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
    > Task :react-native-firebase_firestore:generateReleaseRFile
    > Task :expo-modules-core:compileReleaseKotlin
    w: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/kotlin/records/RecordTypeConverter.kt: (38, 13): Name shadowed: value
    > Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets
    info Writing bundle output to:, /home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/react/release/index.android.bundle
    info Writing sourcemap output to:, /home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/sourcemaps/react/release/index.android.bundle.map
    info Done writing bundle output
    info Done writing sourcemap output
    info Copying 343 asset files
    info Done copying assets
    ReactNativeFirebase WARNING: NPM package '@react-native-firebase/firestore' depends on '@react-native-firebase/app' v14.11.1 but found v14.12.0, this might cause build issues or runtime crashes.
    ReactNativeFirebase WARNING: NPM package '@react-native-firebase/messaging' depends on '@react-native-firebase/app' v15.1.1 but found v14.12.0, this might cause build issues or runtime crashes.
    Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
    Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
    See https://docs.gradle.org/6.9/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
    425 actionable tasks: 425 executed
    [stderr] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
    [stderr] * What went wrong:
    [stderr] Execution failed for task ':react-native-firebase_messaging:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
    [stderr] > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
    [stderr] * Try:
    [stderr] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
    [stderr] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
    [stderr] BUILD FAILED in 5m 28s
```

From what I can understand from the error, this is the major cause:

```
Task :react-native-firebase_messaging:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED
[stderr] An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.8.0_342). Please file a bug against the Java compiler via the Java bug reporting page (http://bugreport.java.com) after checking the Bug Database (http://bugs.java.com) for duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnostic in your report. Thank you.
[stderr] java.lang.AssertionError: annotationType(): unrecognized Attribute name MODULE (class com.sun.tools.javac.util.UnsharedNameTable$NameImpl)
```

I have searched everywhere on stackoverflow and I keep seeing the same [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56567320/task-react-native-firebasecompilereleasejavawithjavac-failed) over and over again

SOLUTION 1:

> Run `npx jetify`

SOLUTION 2:

> Upgrade/downgrade to jdk 11

I have done both successfully. I was always using jdk 11. I have equally checked on android studio to ensure it uses jdk 11 and it does. Also running `java -version` brings out jdk 11:

```
openjdk version "11.0.15" 2022-04-19 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu11.56+19-CA (build 11.0.15+10-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Zulu11.56+19-CA (build 11.0.15+10-LTS, mixed mode)
```

So what else could be wrong?
I have seen a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69235364/genrate-apk-from-react-native-app-jdk-error) to mine. He had the exact same error but his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69536019/18346591) doesn't help my situation because he uses bare react native. I have installed @react-native-firebase/app again but still doesn't fix the problem. I do not know what `./gradlew clean` does as it's only for bare react native projects.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73518928/18346591) suggest making sure my compile or target SDK version are 31 and 30 respectively and I checked my build.gradle and they are set to that by default. I don't know what else to do

Comment: "[stderr] An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.8.0_342)."  -- so you are not using the JDK you think you are using (as indicated by your printout of java -version). Not sure what eas build is doing, but it is using JDK8. You must fix that.

Answer (score 1):

All I needed to add was

```
"production": {
  "android": {
    "image" : "ubuntu-18.04-jdk-11-ndk-r19c"
  }
 }
```

to my eas.json in order for eas to build with jdk11. All thanks to @Mike Hardy